# user identity role assignment runs fine but does show in the portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rm-template, cicd

I am trying to automate my role assignment, and I am using this arm template

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "serviceName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
        "desciption": "nameof the microService"
        }
    },
    "environment": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "nameof enviroment"
        }
    },
    "databaseType": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue":"settings"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "databaseName":"[concat('cosdb',parameters('serviceName'), parameters('environment'), parameters('databaseType'))]",
    "identityName":"[concat('id', parameters('environment'), parameters('serviceName'))]",
    "roleAssignmentId": "[guid(concat(resourceGroup().id, variables('databaseName')))]",
    "roleDefinitionId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlRoleDefinitions', variables('databaseName'), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002')]"
},
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlRoleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-05-15",
            "name": "[concat(variables('databaseName'), '/', variables('roleAssignmentId'))]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('roleDefinitionId')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName')), '2018-11-30').principalId]",
                "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('databaseName'))]"
        }
    }
]
```

}

which runs without issue, but when i look in the portal no roles is assigned,how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you need to give **subscription Id** for the role in the managed identity in roledefinitionId  and roleAssignmentId. Try concat with subscription Id and location if needed.

```
'/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId ,
```

Also if taken from roleDefinitions include  providers in role definitionId
'/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/'

**References**

1. [azure cosmosdb - ARM Template-Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262457/arm-template-microsoft-documentdb-databaseaccounts-sqlroleassignments-updating-s)
2. [Create a CosmosDB Role Assignment using an ARM Template - Microsoft
   Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/463415/create-a-cosmosdb-role-assignment-using-an-arm-tem.html)

Comment: they are scoped to the resouce group, which works without issue using resourceId(),which adds the subsciption and resouce ids, and it actually works for the sdk but it doesn't show in the portal which is odd

Comment: Please check if you have minimum access or permissions to assign roles. [User access administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) or [role administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task#roles-and-administrators) or owner

Comment: i couldn't get it to work so have moved to CLI, but sometimes that doesn't work and i have to just use the portal